# Setting path to upload and email files Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently working on a website with the following functionality:

- Users can post job listings.
- Interested users can click on the job listing, which brings them to an apply page. Here they have to upload their resume via file upload and click on send.
- The resume is now sent to the employers email.

I know how to send my own attachments but I cannot get it to work so users upload their own resumes. Right now, I want to have them saved locally, and not using a different storage like S3. I am also using Paperclip and ActionMailer.

Here is the code that I have:

listings_controller.rb:

```
def send_resume_email
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
        @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        UserMailer.new_resume(@user, @listing).deliver
        redirect_to findjobs_path, notice: 'Message sent'
    end
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
def new_resume(user, listing)
    @listing = listing
    @user = user
    attachments['header.png'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/header.png", mode:     "rb")
    @url = 'http://www.example.com'
    mail(to: listing.user.email, subject: 'Thanks for the awesome site')

end
```

apply.html.erb:

```
<div class="top">
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_tag(listing_send_resume_email_path, :html => { :multipart => true}) do %>

           <%= file_field_tag :file %>
           <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-right' %>
       <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to store uploaded resumes in a model or you just want to mail them?

Comment: at this point I only want to mail them. No need to store them right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to store resumes, Paperclip is not required. You will have to pass file parameter from controller to the mailer.

In Controller:

```
UserMailer.new_resume(@user, @listing, params[:file]).deliver
```

In Mailer:

```
def new_resume(user, listing, file)
    @listing = listing
    @user = user
    @url = 'http://www.example.com'
    attachments["#{file.original_filename}"] = File.read(file.path)
    mail(to: listing.user.email, subject: 'Thanks for the awesome site')
end
```

Also, you might have to modify your form_tag as follows:

```
form_tag(listing_send_resume_email_path, multipart: true)
```

References:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Thank you very much. So it sends something when I upload it. However, when I send an image it says the file is corrupted, damaged or too large. When I send a small docx document it says it cannot be opened becasue there is a problem with the contents.

Comment: Strange. I tried image(jpg), doc and pdf, didn't get any error.

Comment: No, I found that I just had to add File.read(file.path, mode: "rb")